# How to fetch Rows as columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Hi I trying to fetch and display some rows as columns. I dont have any idea how to implement this, but in demand. Here is my table columns

```
**GameDate   StuName      GameName  Participation**
10/10/15   Srini        Football     yes
10/10/15   srini        Hockey       no
10/10/15   srini        Cricket      yes
10/10/15   dev          Football     no
10/10/15   dev          Hockey       yes
10/10/15   dev          Cricket      yes

I want result set as 

**GameDate   StuName    FootBall  Hockey  Cricket**
10/10/15     Srini        yes      no       yes
10/10/15     dev          no       yes      yes
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: i will not know exactly the number of games. it may differ

Comment: There are Tons of examples about **Pivot**, Google them.

Comment: i googled. but i didnt get my exact solutions.  
i will not know exactly the number of games. it may differ. i get solution for fixed columns.

Comment: Use **Dynamic Pivot** as explained into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a Dynamic version.  However, without a column sequence indicator, the columns will be in alphabetical order (ascending or descending --- your choice)

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From YourTable
 Pivot (max([Participation]) 
   For [GameName] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName([GameName]) 
                                  From  YourTable 
                                  Order By 1 
                                  For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The Generated SQL looks like this**

```
Select *
 From YourTable
 Pivot (max([Participation]) 
   For [GameName] in ([Cricket],[Football],[Hockey]) ) p
```

> **Edit - I should add**

If you have additional fields in your source table, change the `From YourTable` to `From (Select GameDate,StuName,GameName,Participation From YourTable) A`  This will limit the fields "feeding" the pivot to just the required elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dynamic Pivot as next Demo:-

```
create table temp
(
    GameDate date,
    StuName varchar(10),
    GameName varchar(10),
    Participation char(3)
)

insert into temp values ('10/10/2015', 'Srini', 'Football','yes')
insert into temp values ('10/10/2015', 'Srini', 'Hockey','no')
insert into temp values ('10/10/2015', 'Srini', 'Cricket','yes')
insert into temp values ('10/10/2015', 'dev', 'Football','no')
insert into temp values ('10/10/2015', 'dev', 'Hockey','yes')
insert into temp values ('10/10/2015', 'dev', 'Cricket','yes')


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.GameName) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT GameDate, StuName,' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select GameDate
                    , StuName
                    , GameName
                    , Participation
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Participation)
                for GameName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

print @query

drop table temp
```

**Output:-**

```
GameDate      StuName     Cricket   Football    Hockey
2015-10-10      dev        yes        no        yes
2015-10-10      Srini      yes        yes       no
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just also use sub-queries to handle this problem. I think it's the simplest one.

```
    CREATE TABLE #test
    (
         GameDate DATE DEFAULT('10/10/15')
        ,StuName NVARCHAR(50)
        ,GameName NVARCHAR(50)
        ,Participation NVARCHAR(50)
    );

    INSERT INTO #test(StuName, GameName, Participation) VALUES
    ('Srini','Football','yes'),
    ('Srini','Hockey','no'),
    ('Srini','Crickiet','yes'),
    ('dev','Football','no'),
    ('dev','Hockey','yes'),
    ('dev','Crickiet','yes');

    SELECT DISTINCT GameDate, StuName, 
        (SELECT Participation FROM #test AS t2 WHERE t1.StuName = t2.StuName AND t2.GameName = 'Football') AS Football,
        (SELECT Participation FROM #test AS t2 WHERE t1.StuName = t2.StuName AND t2.GameName = 'Hockey') AS Hockey,
        (SELECT Participation FROM #test AS t2 WHERE t1.StuName = t2.StuName AND t2.GameName = 'Crickiet') AS Crickiet
    FROM #test AS t1;
```